# Converting HyperInt Hlog to Polylogtool G

Tags: replacement, special-functions, string-manipulation, import

how do I replace efficiently HyperInt's Hlog (in maple expression)

{Hlog(Y,[1]),Hlog(X, [1, -Y + 1]),Hlog(X,[1,1,1])}

in an expression into PolyLogTool G:

{G[1,Y],G[1,-Y+1,X],G[1,1,1,X]}

Basically, the first argument in Hlog become the last indice for G and the square bracket in Hlog going to the front set of indices of G keeping order fixed.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this forum is for Q&A about the software application Mathematica and the Wolfram Language, questions concerning Maple are not appropriate.

Comment: I am just wanting to translate maple expression to mathematical and do calculation to mathematica.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following function works for your example, at least:

```
fromHlog[strExpr_String] :=
  ToExpression[StringReplace[strExpr, {"[" -> "{", "]" -> "}"}], TraditionalForm] /.
  {Hlog[x_, m_List] :> G[Sequence @@ m, x]};
```

though I'm not familiar with the Maple syntax and so it may have some pitfalls.

Usage:

```
fromHlog["{Hlog(Y,[1]),Hlog(X, [1, -Y + 1]),Hlog(X,[1,1,1])}"]
```

Comment: thank you very much tueda! It works